# Not able to route to another page due to structure angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, nebular, ngx-admin

Folder Structure.

```
>app
>>auth
  >>> login
  >>> register
>>pages
  >>> dashboard
```

I want to redirect to login page if user is not logged in, Redirect fires because of condition but the page is not loaded.

My auth folder is out of pages folder so I guess the issue occur, else when the auth folder inside the pages folder, it was working fine.

I guess I have made some mistakes for routing.

Thanks in advance for help.

pages-routing.module

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
// import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
// import { ECommerceComponent } from './e-commerce/e-commerce.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './miscellaneous/not-found/not-found.component';
import { MembershipComponent } from './membership/membership.component';
import { RuleDefinitionComponent } from './rule-definition/rule-definition.component';
import { PointsDashboardComponent } from './points-dashboard/points-dashboard.component';
import { RewardsDefinitionComponent } from './rewards-definition/rewards-definition.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
    },
    // {
    //   path: 'auth',
    //   loadChildren: () => import('../auth/auth.module')
    //     .then(m => m.AuthModule),
    // },
    // {
    //   path: 'auth',
    //   loadChildren: '../auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
    // },
    {
      path: 'miscellaneous',
      loadChildren: () => import('./miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module')
        .then(m => m.MiscellaneousModule),
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'dashboard',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    },
  ],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

app.Routing.module

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

auth.routes.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NbAuthComponent } from '@nebular/auth';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
    ],
}];
```

Comment: Where are you using Auth Route?

Comment: When the auth folder is inside the pages folder it was used in pages-routing.module ,  now no calling components directly.

Comment: Here is the auth.routes.ts
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NbAuthComponent } from '@nebular/auth';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
    ],
}];

Comment: I am saying in which module you have registered this authRouting?

Comment: Now in app module as per my first comment.

Comment: Any errors on console?

Comment: No errors, IT shows redirect in url but not able to see the page content.